# Deactivate soft delete in Gorm

Tags: go-gorm

I want to use the Gorm ['gorm.Model'](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#gorm-Model) for my data models but this contains the DeletedAt field which activates the soft deletion feature. Is there a way to deactivate it or do I have to duplicate this struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete matched records permanently with Unscoped
db.Unscoped().Delete(&order)

https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Delete-permanently

Answer (score 0):

You can find soft deleted records with Unscoped().
Add .Unscoped() to gorm query.

eg.

> db.Unscoped().Where("age = 20").Find(&users)

// SELECT * FROM users WHERE age = 20;

it will exclude the "deleted_at is null" condition

[1]: https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#:~:text=Soft%20Delete&text=DeletedAt%20field%20(which%20is%20included,with%20normal%20Query%20methods%20anymore.